# What in my manifest fle is keeping me limited to 240 tablet devices, with no phones?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-manifest

We are trying to roll out our first android application.  It tests fine in the various screen-size emulators from 10.1 to 3.1.  However, when we try to upload the apk to the site, it indicates we only can be used on 240 devices and looking in random categories, such as Motorola, no cell phone devices are listed.

Further, the application cannot be found on android phones.

Would it be due to the fact that I require a touch screen?

This is what lists on the developer console:
Screen layouts: SMALL NORMAL LARGE XLARGE
Screen densities: 
Required device features
android.hardware.touchscreen

And here is my manifest file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.serioustangents.spellingquiz" android:versionCode="4" android:versionName="1.2.2">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" /> 
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="True" android:normalScreens="True" android:largeScreens="True" android:xlargeScreens="True" android:anyDensity="true" /> 
- <application android:icon="@drawable/beesquare" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.serioustangents.spellingquiz.SpellingBeeApp">
- <activity android:name=".SpellingQuiz" android:label="@string/app_name">
- <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
  </intent-filter>
  </activity>
- <activity android:name=".gameplay" android:label="@string/app_name">
- <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
  </intent-filter>
  </activity>
- <activity android:name=".ChangeUsername" android:label="@string/app_name">
- <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
  </intent-filter>
  </activity>
- <activity android:name=".openingScreen" android:label="@string/app_name">
- <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
  </intent-filter>
  </activity>
- <activity android:name=".closingScreen" android:label="@string/app_name">
- <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
  </intent-filter>
  </activity>
- <activity android:name=".HighScoreScreen" android:label="@string/app_name">
- <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
  </intent-filter>
  </activity>
- <activity android:name=".summaryScreen" android:label="@string/app_name">
- <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
  </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  </application>
  </manifest>
```

Any ideas on why the system will not allow me to set this up for phones?

Comment: Whats with minSDKVersion set to 11?

Comment: You should also change this line `<supports-screens android:smallScreens="True" android:normalScreens="True" android:largeScreens="True" android:xlargeScreens="True" android:anyDensity="true" />` in the manifest so that the values are **"true"** (all lowercase) instead of **"True"** (mixed case). I'm not sure if this has an effect or not, but the documentation indicates that allowed values are "true" and "false".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your minSdkVersion is set to 11, which is Honeycomb. None of the phones run Honeycomb as it is a tablet only version of Android. Try setting it lower. See http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html#intro for details on other API levels.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  After switching the API level to 7 I was able to reach a much wider audience.

Answer (score 3):

Your minSdkVersion is 11, which is 3.0 Honeycomb.  Your app will only be visible by tablets running Honeycomb and phones and tablets with 4.0 (ICS) or higher.  The vast majority of phones out there right now are running 2.2 or 2.3.